# How to add image to table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, imageview, background-image

Im trying to add an image as a background behind  table view controller with multiple cells,already I'm using an imageView but having an issue where the background doesn't go behind the text but above or below the cells.

[image]

My file structure looks like:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to add image in overall tableview background?

Comment: @Sherin Yeah I would like the image to be displayed behind the content instead of the black background.

Comment: @Sherin Yes they are static.

Comment: Check my answer, it will work perfectly. Make sure both tableview and tableview cells background color should be 'clearcolor'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set overall background image to a **UITableView** use below code

```
var backGroundImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:  "backGroundImage.png"))
self.tableView.backgroundView = backGroundImage
```

Comment: Thanks Sherin your code worked. Also had to change the tableViewsClass but then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
     let img:UIImageView=UIImageView(frame: PostTable.frame)
     img.image=UIImage(named: "hi.png")
     PostTable.backgroundView=img
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

        let selectView=UIView()
        selectView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.selectedBackgroundView=selectView
        cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change the property of the background color for Tableview : clear background